# Spark SQL - reading csv with schema

Tags: scala, validation, csv, apache-spark, schema

I encountered the problem while trying to use Spark for simple reading a CSV file. After such operation I would like to ensure that:

- the data types are correct (with using provided schema)
- the headers are correct against provided schema

That's the code I use and have problems with:

```
val schema = Encoders.product[T].schema
val df = spark.read
 .schema(schema)
 .option("header", "true")
 .csv(fileName)
```

The type `T` is of type `Product`, i. e. case class. This works but it doesn't check if **column names** are correct, so I can give another file and as long as the data types are correct the error doesn't occur and I am unaware that the user provided the wrong file but by some coincidence with correct data types with the proper ordering.

I tried to use options which infers the schema and then use `.as[T]` method on Dataset, but in case when any column other than `String` contains only null it's interpreted by Spark as `String` column, but in my schema it is `Integer`. So cast exception occurs, but column names has been checked all right.

To summarize: I found solution that I can ensure correct data types but no headers and other solution that I can validate headers but have problems with data types. Is there any way to achieve both, i. e. complete validation of headers and types?

I am using Spark 2.2.0.

Comment: @mrsrinivas - thank you for your comment, I read your answer but how does it help with my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to do it yourself by reading the file header *twice*.

Looking at Spark's code, the inferred header is completely **ignored** (never actually read) if a user supplies their own schema, so there's no way of making Spark fail on such an inconsistency.

To perform this comparison yourself:

```
val schema = Encoders.product[T].schema

// read the actual schema; This shouldn't be too expensive as Spark's
// laziness would avoid actually reading the entire file 
val fileSchema = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("test.csv").schema

// read the file using your own schema. You can later use this DF
val df = spark.read.schema(schema)
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("test.csv")

// compare actual and expected column names:
val badColumnNames = fileSchema.fields.map(_.name)
  .zip(schema.fields.map(_.name))
  .filter { case (actual, expected) => actual != expected }

// fail if any inconsistency found:
assert(badColumnNames.isEmpty, 
  s"file schema does not match expected; Bad column names: ${badColumnNames.mkString("; ")}")
```

Comment: it looks like an overkill to me - let's assume that I am loading very big csv file, I have to load it twice to memory just for header? Wouldn't it better in that case to write few lines of code which will read in only the first line and parse it into headers manualy and then I will make comparison?

Comment: Since Spark is lazy, and reading the header requires only the first line, and we're not enabling `inferSchema` which requires scanning through all/some of the data - this shouldn't result in loading the entire file twice. I think (although not sure of the details) only the first _partition_ would actually be read from disk. So - overhead? Some, but not much.

Comment: i suppose in case when transformation process will take few hours 1 sec its not serious )